# How to exclude certain types/categories from Google Places API results?

Tags: filtering, google-places-api

I want to exclude individual doctor's offices in my results.

Most doctor's offices are in the category "doctor" and "health".

I DO want to show places of category "health".

How can I achieve this?

If I remove "doctor" from the types parameter, but still have "health", i'll still get all the doctor's offices.

Is there a way to specifically exclude type "doctor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with out manually filtering them out of your results. This sounds like a great feature request, please file it as a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) on the Google Maps issue tracker.

Comment: Any chance this feature exists now, 2.5 years later?

Comment: See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822993 from a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531190/3294944