# Google Places API - getPlacePredictions exclude specific business types from results?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am working on a search plugin for our website that allows users to search any location with the Google Places API and list our apartments and their distance to that location.

To restrict the search for the users I added some possible restrictions to the method: `getPlacePredictions()` that can be used within the Google Places API object `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()`.

**Country:** only Germany

**Preferred search Area:** northrhine-westfalia (a region in germany)

```
    function pacGetSuggestions(searchString) {
        // set autocomplete options
        var pacOptions      = {
            input                       : searchString,
            componentRestrictions       : {country: 'de'},          // restrict results to germany
            bounds                      : pacDefaultBounds,         // add search area
        };
        // get suggestions
        PAC.getPlacePredictions(pacOptions, pacDrawSuggestions);    
    }
```

this works fine so far!

**My Question:**

How can I limit the results by specific location-types? Is there any way?

**Example:**

I don't want users to be able to search for hotels/hostels and so on, because that would be direct competition for us.

If the user types "Hil" for "Hill-Street" or "HillyBilly Pizza Place" then she should not get the "Hilton Hotels, Somethingstreet..." displayed.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude certain types/categories from Google Places API results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960698/how-to-exclude-certain-types-categories-from-google-places-api-results)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find supported types:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

You can filter by country as well:
components — A grouping of places to which you would like to restrict your results. Currently, you can use components to filter by country. The country must be passed as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. For example: components=country:fr would restrict your results to places within France.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

I hope it helps you.