# Is it possible to exclude some 'types' from the Google Places API responses?

Tags: python, json, web-services, google-places-api

I have a travel site that lists the POI of each city. So I use the Google Places API to return points of interest like this:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=45.8150108,15.981919&radius=10000&types=point_of_interest&hasNextPage=true&nextPage()=true&sensor=false&key=My_Key
```

However, in addition to POI it returns other types like this:

```
  "types": [
    "travel_agency",
    "real_estate_agency",
    "lodging",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
  ],
```

Which causes returning things like hotels and offices instead of just POI, is there a way to force return just POI ? I tried using `type` instead of `types` but it still returns other `types`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot exclude certain types from Places API searches. There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to add this functionality.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822993

You can star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Please note that endpoint `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json` is not documented.

There are following endpoints for [Places API searches](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search):

- Nearby search `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters`
- Radar search `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/output?parameters`
- Text search `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/output?parameters`

You should use one of them. Also the `types` parameter was deprecated in February 2016:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#deprecation

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) says that `output` can be either `json` or `xml`, so the endpoint is actually right.